# Simple insert query in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've manipulated my data into the format I need it using a view, and now I have a simple insert query to write that data to a table:

```
insert into mytable
select * from myview
where 
(myview.[date] > (select max([date]) from mytable))
and 
(myview.[date] < getdate())
```

I'd like this to run automatically on a daily basis. I am a bit new to this, but my understanding is that I need to utilize a stored procedure. I am not sure how to execute this code in my stored procedure, though. When I create a new stored procedure, I'm given this template:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update]
    @param1 int = 0,
    @param2 int
AS
    SELECT @param1, @param2
RETURN 0
```

Could someone help me understand how to bridge from query to stored procedure?

Comment: First I would not suggest doing a select * into a table as the number of columns could change in your source table w/o them changing in the target table.  So in your insert do it more like this: `insert into mytable ( col1, col2, col3 ) select col1, col2, col3 from myview where ...` Also you don't need to create a procedure for this...a simple SQL Job and a task should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this and it will create a stored procedure in sql server called the_name_of_your_sproc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[the_name_of_your_sproc]
AS
    insert into mytable
    select * from myview
    where 
    (myview.[date] > (select max([date]) from mytable))
    and 
    (myview.[date] < getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

The procedure definition would be as simple as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Upload_data
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into mytable
    select * from myview
    where 
    (myview.[date] > (select max([date]) from mytable))
    and 
    (myview.[date] < getdate())

END
```

Once you have created the procedure , create a SQL Agent job which calls this procedure every day.